# Extension element not associated with an extension collection

Tags: wcf

I am getting a warning being logged in WCF tracing when I try to configure an  extension using the following configuration:

```
<bindingElementExtensions>
  <add name="noeMaxCompression" type="Noemax.WCFX.Configuration.CompressionElement, Noemax.WCFX, Version=15.78.5133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4c0defa954f97f18" />
</bindingElementExtensions>
<bindingExtensions>
  <add name="noeMaxExtensionBinding" type="Noemax.WCFX.Configuration.ExtensionBindingCollectionElement, Noemax.WCFX, Version=15.78.5133.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4c0defa954f97f18" />
</bindingExtensions>
```

This is then used by extending a custom configured netTcp binding, like so (snipped for brevity):

```
<bindings>
  <noeMaxExtensionBinding>
    <binding name="noemaxBinding" sourceBinding="netTcpBinding" sourceBindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_DefaultConfiguration" >
      <noeMaxCompression compressionLevel="3"/>
    </binding>
  </noeMaxExtensionBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding
      name="NetTcpBinding_DefaultConfiguration"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      portSharingEnabled="false"
      >
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Here is the warning that is logged:

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
  <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/System.ServiceModel.ExtensionCollectionNameNotFound.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
  <Description>Extension element not associated with an extension collection.</Description>
  <AppDomain>ServicesHost.Console.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
  <Source>Noemax.WCFX.Configuration.CompressionElement/1</Source>
</TraceRecord>
```

Does anybody know what the extension collection refers to/how to resolve this warning?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this error?